# looping from 1 to 50 after the automatic pause for 30 seconds and further looping to 51 to 100 and so on

Tags: javascript, imacros

How do I submit looping from 1 to 10. And then pause for 10 seconds. And then looping from 11 to 20. And so on
Please help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not create software for you. Create the code by yourself first and ask questions about your not working code.

Comment: `submit looping` ? `automatic pause` ? that makes zero sense - and why is the title of the question and the body almost exactly the same question with completely different "values"?

Comment: So sounds like you need a timeout

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question:

```js
var count = 0;
function counter (count) {
  if(count < 50) {
    var limit = count + 10;
    for(var i = count; i <= limit; i++) {         
      console.log(i);
      this.count = i;
    }
  }
}

counter(count);
setInterval(function() {
  counter(count);
}, 10000);
```

Have fun and try to write code by yourself.